# JavaScript: Variable is false but if statement is true?

Tags: javascript, boolean

I have this JS code:

```
var show = elm.hasClassName('level0') ? false : true;
if(show) {
  doSomething()
}
```

I am using FireBug to check the value of show and it clearly states **false**. While debugging, I noticed that the doSomething function is called anyway. What am I missing?

Using if(false) does not run the doSomething function.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `var show = !elm.hasClassName('level0')`, does that make any difference?

Comment: @Kolink1: Same result, it runs doSomething() ...

Comment: no need for a ternary operator, just use hasClassName directly

Comment: @NimChimpsky: That doesnt help either

Comment: lol, no but its a better style

Comment: if(!elm.hasClassName('level0'))  - does it run doSomething?

Comment: Even if I set the value of show to "0" or "1" and make a string comparison it runs doSomething, no matter what show is.

Comment: @d'alar'cop: Yes, it does

Comment: AND if(elm.hasClassName('level0'))... same?

Comment: @d'alar'cop: Same, it runs doSomething()

Comment: If you can show your HTML as well or build a Fiddle..We can help further

Comment: @user1856596 please can you put your code complete ??

Comment: this cannot be the source of the problem, more code would be helpful

Comment: I tried in a fiddle, it works there ... even if I assing false to show, it runs doSomething! What the ****, strange thing.

Comment: Show us the fiddle :)

Comment: Yes, more of the contextual code would be good... this condition he describes seems to be impossible - a contradiction - a paradox

Comment: mind sharing the fiddle ?

Comment: Only if I say if(false) it does NOT run doSomething(). Fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/g4Zqp/, but as I said, it works there.

Comment: I tried to implement exactly what you have. It seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/g4Zqp/2/

Answer (score 2):

From whatever code you have shown (!!!), I believe that your debugging is wrong. May be you are seeing the value of

`elm.hasClassName('level0')` 
 as 
`false`

But, `var show = elm.hasClassName('level0') ? false : true;` means `show` will be set to inverse of `elm.hasClassName('level0')`

Just add an `alert(show)` above the if condition and see what is printed. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g4Zqp/1/ It works perfectly fine.

If this is not the case, you need to put your complete code

Comment: +1, this is definitely the case. Or his `doSomething()` gets called from somewhere else in the code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if( !elm.hasClassName('level0')) {
  doSomething()
}
```